# Zeroclipboard and Boostrap Tooltip Disappearing Bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, zeroclipboard

I'm using [Zeroclipboard](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard) to let users copy a link to their clipboard.  For this feature, I'm trying to use Bootstrap's tooltips to show a pop up message ("copy link to clipboard") when the user first hovers over the link.  After they click the link, the tooltip text should change to "copied!"

I am able to get the clipboard functionality to work and get the tooltip text to change to "copied!"  However, when the user initially hovers over the link, the tooltip flashes before it disappears from view.

This seems to be a reported issue here, but none of the suggestions have worked for me:

https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard/issues/369

This is what I currently have:

```
 <div class="name step_link" data-clipboard-text="<%=project_steps_url(@project, :step=>step.id) %>" title="copy link to clipboard" rel="tooltip" ><%= step.name %>
    </div>

<script>
 var clip = new ZeroClipboard($(".step_link"));
 var default_copy_text = "copy link to clipboard";

 $('.step_link').tooltip({
     title: default_copy_text, 
     placement: 'bottom'
 });

 clip.on('aftercopy', function(event){
    $(event.target).attr('data-original-title', 'copied!');
    $(event.target).tooltip({placement: 'bottom'}).mouseover();
 });
</script>
```

Interestingly, if I add the following:

```
document.getElementById('global-zeroclipboard-html-bridge').style.position = 'fixed' ;
```

the tooltip doesn't flash, but then nothing gets copied to the clipboard!  (I found this tip here: http://mrjoelkemp.com/2013/06/zeroclipboard-with-a-bootstrap-modal/)

Any help is greatly appreciated!